# Capacitance with two different dielectrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, capacitance, dielectric

> A parallel-plate capacitor with plates of area $LW$ and plate separation $t$ has the region between its plates filled with wedges of two dielectric materials as shown in figure down below. Assume $t$ is much less than both $L$ and $W$. Determine its capacitance.
> [image]

I tried to study the capacitance on a small portion $dx$ on $L$ but I am not able to use the formula of the capacitance for a parallel-plate $C=\epsilon_0 A/d$. Can someone help me ?

Comment: u are  on the right track. The formula for cap. with different dieelctrics inside is different....btw does the wedge extend in $\hat{W}$ direction

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the capacitance of a cap. with stacked dielectrics of thickness $d_i$ and dielectric constant $k_i$ is given by

$$\frac 1 {C_{stack}}=\sum_i\frac 1 {C_i}\tag{1}$$

where $C_i=k_i\epsilon_0 A/d_i$. This is obtained by treating the inner space of the multi-dielectric cap. as a series connection of multiple single dielectric caps. filled with just those dielectrics.

For your question imagine a $dC_{stack,x}$ in every $(x,x+dx)$. The full cap. $C$, is then just the parallel connection of each of these caps.
$$C=\int_0^L dC_{stack,x}\tag{2}$$

---

**Sol.**

The dividing line starts on the bottom left corner at $(0,0)$ and stops at the top right corner $(L,H)$, where I have taken $H=t$. The line's eqn. is
$$y=H x/L\tag{3}$$
The dielectric thicknesses are
$$
d_1=H-y\hspace{1cm} d_2=y \tag{4}
$$
The caps are

$$
C_1=\frac{k_1\epsilon_0 dx\,W}{H(1-x/L)} \hspace{1cm} C_2=\frac{k_2\epsilon_0 dx\,W}{Hx/L} \tag{5}
$$
The cap at $x$ using eqns. $1,5$ is

$$
\begin{align}
dC_{stack,x}&=\frac{C_1 C_2}{C_1+C_2}\tag{6}\\
&=C_0\frac{k_1 k_2 dx}{(k_1-k_2)x+k_2L}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
where $C_0=\frac{\epsilon_0 LW}{H}$ is the capacitance of the whole system without any dielectric.

The total capacitance using eqns. $2,7$ is

$$
C=C_0\int_0^L\frac{k_1 k_2 dx}{(k_1-k_2)x+k_2L}\tag{7}
$$
giving
$$
C=
\begin{cases}
C_0 \frac{k_1k_2}{k_1-k_2}\ln\frac {k_1}{k_2} & k_1\ne k_2\\
C_0 k & k_1=k_2=k
\end{cases}
$$